# Dynamic Form Data with Python CGI

Tags: python, cgi, form-data

Recently, I decided to learn basic Python CGI. The best way to practice was to make up a simple project in my head and then to implement it. The project is this: I will generate a form, first consisted of an "input type text" to get a grade and then two "input type submit"s, one of which is "add new grade" and the other is "calculate"... First the user will enter a grade and if he submits calculate, the grade will be converted to base 4 GPA. But as long as (s)he submits add new grade, new "input type text" will keep being generated and (s)he will enter as many grades as (s)he wants and then proceeds to submit calculate, which will return the base 4 GPA. Well, at least it was what I wanted to achieve.

I use WAMP on my windows 10 PC.

But I have two problems. The first is, I can't set up my WAMP server to run the script I wrote. That's why I don't if it will work as intended. I went to my `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf` directory and in the `httpd.conf` file, I added the line `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews ExecCGI` in its appropriate place and uncommented the line `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py`. Then I put my script in the directory `C:\wamp\www\`. But my browser just keeps searching and then gives a timeout message.

The second problem is that I'm suspicious if the code will work as intended because I didn't know how to check if any of the "input type submit"s is set. My script is exactly as following:

```js
#!C:\Users\Nima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Python.exe
import cgi

def convertNearestBase(point):
bases = [0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 1.3, 1.7, 2.0, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.7, 4.0]
minVal = 0.4
result = 0

for base in bases:
    if minVal > abs(point - base):
        minVal = abs(point - base)
        result = base

return result


def convertSinglePoint(point):
transpoint = point/20 - 1

return convertNearestBase(transpoint)


i = 1
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
sumVal = convertSinglePoint(form.getvalue("point1"))
addNew = form.getvalue("addNew")
calc = form.getvalue("calculate")

print('Content-Type: text/plain\n\n')
print('<html><head><title>Online GPA Converter</title>')
print('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" /></head>')
print('<body><h1>Online GPA Converter</h1><div class="container">')
print('<form method="post" action="">')
print('Enter point: <input type="number" name="point1" min="0" max="100" />')
print('<input type="submit" name="addNew" value="Add New" />')
while not calc:
if addNew:
    i += 1
    textEditName = "point" + str(i)
    print('Enter point: <input type="number" name="{}" min="0" max="100" />'.format(textEditName))
    print('<input type="submit" name="addNew" value="Add New" />')
    point = form.getvalue(textEditName)
    sumVal += convertSinglePoint(point)

print('<input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate GPA" />')
print('</form></div>')

finalPoint = convertNearestBase(sumVal/i)
if calc:
print('<p>Your GPA is {}</p>'.format(finalPoint))

print('</body></html>')
```

I know I'm asking for too much, but I really need help. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Nima, CGI is really outdated technology. For two reasons: it's performance and complexity. CGI spawns new process for every request. This adds too much overhead. Modern alternative is FastCGI. But it itself is way too low level. If you just want to learn how to write web applications on Python it is better to start with one of modern frameworks. I suggest using flask because it is really minimalistic and simple, yet very powerful and well documented. And it has built-in web server suitable for debug purposes.

Comment: I'm not going to use it for any practical applications. I am just learning. BTW, I've tried Django a few years ago and hated it. But unfortunately your post fails to answer the question. Also, what do you guys use at Yandex? Not flask, right?

Comment: There are many working groups in Yandex and we use different tools. So I can't speak for whole Yandex. But most of our production services is written on C++ (backend) or node.js (some of frontends which I know). Python is mostly used for backoffice tasks. And yes, here we use flask.

Comment: wow, that's great! It must be very cool to work for Yandex. But I'm only a beginner and I'd like to get an answer to my question from a master such as you.